# How to monitor bandwidth on a LAN with consumer hardware?

Tags: networking, lan, network-monitoring, quota

I want to install a server running NtopNG for monitoring real-time network usage and logging statistics on usage of my network, specifically the outgoing network traffic, as the LAN shares a quota from my ISP. This is a small, personal traffic LAN so I think a Raspberry Pi should be more than sufficient, but I am a bit unsure of the setup.

I assumed that I needed to somehow route all traffic through this device (meaning it works a bridge?), but from what I could glean from the manual, this did not seem to matter (SNMP would provide the stats). Is is sufficient to simply connect the RasPi to a switch (shared by the LAN)? It seems that for this to work I would need SNMP support in my switch (el cheapo) and/or router (a consumer grade 4G/LTE router: Huawei E5186s). Probably not likely, but maybe I am mistaken. Any other way?

I am assuming the alternative is to put the NtopNG box between the router and th switch, but then I would not get to monitor the wifi traffic going directly to the router. And I am also not super certain NtopNG can analyse traffic when configured as a bridge?

SETUP

```
Client1
     \
     WiFiAP
            \ 
NtopNG <--> Switch <---> Router --> Internet
            /             /
Client2 ---/             /
                        /
Client3 (wifi) --------/
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually for this sort of thing you want your monitoring as close to the network source as possible. In front of your router is a great place but i'ts probably not possible in this setup. Most folks will use a hub in promiscuous mode to allow all traffic to be seen by the monitoring software.

To configure it in this environment you may want to:

- Put the NtopNG between the router and switch.
- Disable WIFI on the router entirely.
- Install an Access Point after the switch for WIFI access that is monitored.

Comment: But isn't hardware with those capabilities (promiscuous mode) in the smb/business level of hardware? I'd like to not spend too much on new hw.

Comment: Not really, hubs are relatively simple and older technology. I would not expect to spend more than $25-50 for a new device but could probably locate a used one for $5 or $10.

Comment: Isn't the reason people stopped using hubs instead of switches that you get a lot of package collisions? That's not so hot. 

I now found that there are modified firmware for consumer routers that will enable snmp: https://fatmin.com/2013/11/13/install-and-configure-snmp-on-the-asus-rt-ac66u-router. Having such a thing in my network at a central point would enable monitoring.

Comment: Yes, packet collision and the necessity to re-transmit data make hubs less efficient than switches. One major benefit, even today, is that they send all traffic to all ports, when you only have an input port and output port and a monitoring port you can easily see everything, and have minimal, if any, concern about collisions.

Comment: So by getting a cheap hub, feeding it the main traffic in, with one port connected the the normal router and one port connected to a monitoring device, you can bypass the need to have SNMP/Netflow support in your other hardware? Clever.